# How to monitor changes to UIPasteboard in real time?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipasteboard

I'm writing a keyboard APP , I want to get the text in pasteboard , so i use `UIPasteboard` and this function `[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard]`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIPasteboard *paste = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];

self.outputLabel.text = paste.string;
```

it works , I can get the string and i know the string i paste is on pasteboard . So i want get the string in paste real-time,i use observe and

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIPasteboard *paste = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
    self.paste = paste;

    self.outputLabel.text = paste.string;

    [paste addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"key" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)change context:(void *)context{

    self.outputLabel.text = self.paste.string;
}
```

but it doesn't work , even the function doesn't run .

Can anybody help me?

Also if anybody have written APP like keyboard , you can send email to me , let's discuss the bug in keyboard :) .My email is yuyanganhui@outlook.com !

Comment: Are you looking for `UIPasteboardChanged`? Change seems to be post a `NSNotification` management.

Comment: thanks for your comment , i had  try . should i use NSNotification defaultCenter ? like this `NSNotification *noti = [NSNotification notificationWithName:@"UIPasteboardChanged" object:nil userInfo:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:noti];
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didChange) name:@"UIPasteboardChanged" object:nil];`but i don't know where i have make wrong then it dose not work